# dynamically allocate an global array that is within a dynamically allocated array of structure

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, struct

I know my question looks confusing, but please take a look of my code:

```
struct name{
   string first
   string last
};
struct course_grade{
   name Name;
   string idNum;
   double *testArrayPtr;
   double average;
   char grade;
};
int num;
int num_test;
course_grade *gradeArr = new course_grade[num]; //this works, no hit of error shown

(*gradeArr).testArrayPtr= new  double[num_test];// error!
```

I'm trying to dynamically allocate an array. The problem is that this array is within another array of structure that I allocated dynamically.
This is the first time I ask a question in Stack, thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message?

Comment: Why not using `std:vector` instead of raw arrays?

Comment: Are `num` and `num_test` really not initialized in your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

This one works:

```
struct name{
   string first
   string last
};
struct course_grade{
   name Name;
   string idNum;
   double *testArrayPtr;
   double average;
   char grade;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int num = 1;
    int num_test = 1;
    course_grade *gradeArr = new course_grade[num]; 
    (*gradeArr).testArrayPtr = new  double[num_test];


    return 0;
}
```

I assume you have not initialised `num` and `num_test`.

Comment: You really should wait for the Q to be answerable before you just assume what the problem is.  For all we know the OP has this.